Django queryset not filtering correctly in ListView with complex lookup
I'm trying to build a Django application where I have a ListView that displays a list of objects based on complex filtering criteria, but I'm encountering issues with the queryset not filtering correctly. Here's a simplified version of my code:
models.py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stock_quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Sale(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_sold = models.IntegerField()
    sale_date = models.CharField()

views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product, Sale

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(category='Electronics', stock_quantity__gte=10, sale__sale_date__month=4)

product_list.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for product in object_list %}
            <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

I expect this ProductListView to display a list of products that belong to the 'Electronics' category, have a stock quantity of at least 10, and have had sales in the current month (April). However, when I visit the page, it displays an empty list, even though I know there are products that meet these criteria.
I've tried debugging by printing the queryset in the get_queryset method, and it seems to be filtering correctly. I'm not sure what's going wrong or how to fix it.
Can someone please help me understand why the queryset is not filtering correctly in the ListView and how I can resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

The issue might be related to the sale__sale_date__month filter. The sale_date field in the Sale model is defined as a CharField, which might not be the best choice for storing dates. It would be better to use a DateField or DateTimeField for storing dates.
However, if you still want to use the CharField for storing dates, you need to make sure that the date format in the sale_date field is consistent and can be correctly parsed by Django. For example, if the sale_date field stores dates in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', you can filter the Product queryset based on the current month like the following:
from django.utils import timezone

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        current_month = timezone.now().month
        return queryset.filter(category='Electronics', stock_quantity__gte=10, sale__sale_date__startswith=f'{current_month}/')


If your sale_date field stores dates in a different format, you'll need to adjust the filter accordingly to match the format of your data.

